# Several questions about d.e $y'(t)+\sin^2(t) y(t)= \left\{\begin{matrix} 6-2t & , & t\in [0,3] \\ 0 & , & t>3 \\ \end{matrix}\right .$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

True or false? Let the linear differential equation of first class:
$$y'(t)+\sin^2(t) y(t)= \left\{\begin{matrix} 6-2t & , & t\in [0,3] \\  0 & , & t>3 \\  \end{matrix}\right .$$
$a)$ There does not exist a solution such that $y(2020)=1010.$

$b)$ For every solution $y$ of the equation holds $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} y(x)=0$.

$c)$ There's exist a $y$ oscillating solution (i.e. $y$ has infinite roots).

$d)$ Every solution $y$ is finally constant (i.e there's exist a $t_0$ such that, for all $t\geq t_0$ $y(t)=const.)$

I understand that it doesn't need to solve the equation to answer these quastions (and I can't solve it from the other side because we can not compute the integral) but its difficult for me to give the correct answer in these questions only from the equation. For example to $(d)$ if every solution $y$ is finally constant to $[0,+\infty)$ then  there's exist a $t_0$ such that, for all $t\geq t_0$ $y(t)=c,$ thus $y'(t)=0,t\geq t_0$. Then, by replacing to equation (and w.l.o.g supposing that $t_0> 3$) we have:
$0+c\sin^2 (t)=0, \ \forall t\geq t_0$ then what? Am I missing something? The same problem appearing to all other quastions, I end up to a point that I can't continue. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see if $t\in[0,3]$, the solution the equation is
$$ y(t)=e^{\frac14(-2t+\sin(2t))}\bigg(y_0+\int_0^te^{\frac14(2s-\sin(2s))}(6-2s)ds\bigg) $$
and if $t>3$, the solution the equation is
$$y(t)=e^{\frac14(-2t+\sin(2t))}(y_0+a) \tag{1}$$
where
$$ a=\int_0^3e^{\frac14(2s-\sin(2s))}(6-2s)ds. $$
Since $2020>3$, then
$$ y(2020)=e^{\frac14(-4040+\sin(4040))}(y_0+a)=e^{-1010+\frac14\sin(4040)}(y_0+a). $$
Note that $e^{-1010+\frac14\sin(4040)}$ is very small positive number. If $y(2020)=1010$, the initial condition $y_0$ satisfies
$$ y_0=1010e^{1010-\frac14\sin(4040)}-a $$
which is a very big number. This answers (a). From (1), it is easy to see $\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)=0$ which is (b). Clearly $y(t)$ is not oscillating and not finally constant, which answers (c) and (d).

Update: If $y_0+a>0$, then (1) implies $y(t)>0$ and if $y_0+a>0$, then (1) implies $y(t)<0$. Thus $y(t)$ is not changing signs and hence is not oscillating. This answers (c).

Comment: So, (a) is wrong because you find a solution s.t y(2020)=1010 and
(c) is wrong because ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: yes but how can I explain there are not exist oscillating solutions with the definition? Monotone?

Comment: It depends on $y_0$ and $a$. For $t>3$, if $y_0+a>0$, then $y(t)>0$ and if $y_0+a<0$, then $y(t)<0$.

Comment: Firstly, is there any solution that has on [0,3] infinitly many roots? Why are you reffering only at second  part of the function?
Secondly, is there any possibility $y_0+a=0$?

Comment: for example the function $\sin (\frac{1}{x})$ is oscillating at $(0,1]$

Comment: This one is different from $\sin(1/x)$. See the update.

Comment: I make this question then: Is the function $f(x)=2+\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ oscillating?  If I make a transposition
to x'x it is. An oscillating function says that the roots of f(x)=0,are infinete, or the roots of $f(x)=c$, for some c, are infinete? Essentially, oscillation describes a physical phenomenon, so should we intrested about what happens below the equilibrium position of an object, whoever it is ($0$ or some $ c$)? If I am right then the sign of $f$ doesn't play any role about oscillation.

Comment: Since $f(x)=2+\sin(1/x)>0$, it is not oscillating.